Is there a way to resume tuning with an optimizer from mealpy after it has been reloaded?
My question is as the title says.
I'm planning to tune a neural network with PSO from mealpy, so I plan to run some of it on Colab, and I'm worried about running out of computing units before training is complete. I know mealpy allows the optimizer to be saved so I can access it's history, but I'm not sure how to resume tuning afterward.
Here is my sample code:
from mealpy import MixedSetVar, PSO
from mealpy.utils import io
import numpy as np
#numbers in each set aka array get sorted by cardinality
hyperparameter_choices = [
    [8, 19, 10],  # First hyperparameter (e.g., number of filters in the first layer)
    [16, 27, 18],  # Second hyperparameter
    [32, 43, 34],  # Third hyperparameter
    [158, 127, 126, 125, 124, 1],  # Fourth hyperparameter
    [2,1,4, 5, 0.5]
]

bounds = MixedSetVar(valid_sets=hyperparameter_choices)

def objective_function(solution):
    decoded_solution = bounds.decode(solution)

    # Return the sum of squares of the hyperparameter values minus the penalty
    fitness_value = np.sum(np.array(decoded_solution) ** 2) 
    return fitness_value

problem_dict = {
    "obj_func": objective_function,
    "bounds": bounds,
    "minmax": "min",
    "verbose": True,
    "save_population": True       # Then you can't draw the trajectory chart
}
model = PSO.OriginalPSO(epoch=10, pop_size=50)
g_best = model.solve(problem=problem_dict)

print(f"Best Solution: {g_best.solution}, Fitness: {g_best.target.fitness}")
print(f"Best Decoded Solution: {bounds.decode(g_best.solution)}, Fitness: {g_best.target.fitness}")

## Save model to file
io.save_model(model, "./model.pkl")

## Load the model from file
model2 = io.load_model("./model.pkl")
print(f"Best solution: {model2.g_best.solution}, Best fitness: {model2.g_best.target.fitness}")

Here is the output of the model history:
2024/10/13 09:17:48 AM, INFO, mealpy.swarm_based.PSO.OriginalPSO: Solving single objective optimization problem.
2024/10/13 09:17:48 AM, INFO, mealpy.swarm_based.PSO.OriginalPSO: >>>Problem: P, Epoch: 1, Current best: 1349.0, Global best: 1349.0, Runtime: 0.00453 seconds
2024/10/13 09:17:48 AM, INFO, mealpy.swarm_based.PSO.OriginalPSO: >>>Problem: P, Epoch: 2, Current best: 1345.25, Global best: 1345.25, Runtime: 0.00685 seconds
2024/10/13 09:17:48 AM, INFO, mealpy.swarm_based.PSO.OriginalPSO: >>>Problem: P, Epoch: 3, Current best: 1345.25, Global best: 1345.25, Runtime: 0.00446 seconds
2024/10/13 09:17:48 AM, INFO, mealpy.swarm_based.PSO.OriginalPSO: >>>Problem: P, Epoch: 4, Current best: 1345.25, Global best: 1345.25, Runtime: 0.00486 seconds
2024/10/13 09:17:48 AM, INFO, mealpy.swarm_based.PSO.OriginalPSO: >>>Problem: P, Epoch: 5, Current best: 1345.25, Global best: 1345.25, Runtime: 0.00537 seconds
2024/10/13 09:17:48 AM, INFO, mealpy.swarm_based.PSO.OriginalPSO: >>>Problem: P, Epoch: 6, Current best: 1345.25, Global best: 1345.25, Runtime: 0.00496 seconds
2024/10/13 09:17:48 AM, INFO, mealpy.swarm_based.PSO.OriginalPSO: >>>Problem: P, Epoch: 7, Current best: 1345.25, Global best: 1345.25, Runtime: 0.00472 seconds
2024/10/13 09:17:48 AM, INFO, mealpy.swarm_based.PSO.OriginalPSO: >>>Problem: P, Epoch: 8, Current best: 1345.25, Global best: 1345.25, Runtime: 0.00585 seconds
2024/10/13 09:17:48 AM, INFO, mealpy.swarm_based.PSO.OriginalPSO: >>>Problem: P, Epoch: 9, Current best: 1345.25, Global best: 1345.25, Runtime: 0.00529 seconds
2024/10/13 09:17:48 AM, INFO, mealpy.swarm_based.PSO.OriginalPSO: >>>Problem: P, Epoch: 10, Current best: 1345.25, Global best: 1345.25, Runtime: 0.00506 seconds
Best Solution: [0 0 0 0 0], Fitness: 1345.25
Best Decoded Solution: [8, 16, 32, 1, 0.5], Fitness: 1345.25

This is what I used to  resume model training and the output history:
model2.solve(problem=problem_dict)

2024/10/13 10:43:47 AM, INFO, mealpy.swarm_based.PSO.OriginalPSO: Solving single objective optimization problem.
2024/10/13 10:43:47 AM, INFO, mealpy.swarm_based.PSO.OriginalPSO: >>>Problem: P, Epoch: 1, Current best: 1381.25, Global best: 1381.25, Runtime: 0.00397 seconds
2024/10/13 10:43:47 AM, INFO, mealpy.swarm_based.PSO.OriginalPSO: >>>Problem: P, Epoch: 2, Current best: 1345.25, Global best: 1345.25, Runtime: 0.00502 seconds
2024/10/13 10:43:47 AM, INFO, mealpy.swarm_based.PSO.OriginalPSO: >>>Problem: P, Epoch: 3, Current best: 1345.25, Global best: 1345.25, Runtime: 0.00604 seconds
2024/10/13 10:43:47 AM, INFO, mealpy.swarm_based.PSO.OriginalPSO: >>>Problem: P, Epoch: 4, Current best: 1345.25, Global best: 1345.25, Runtime: 0.01040 seconds
2024/10/13 10:43:47 AM, INFO, mealpy.swarm_based.PSO.OriginalPSO: >>>Problem: P, Epoch: 5, Current best: 1345.25, Global best: 1345.25, Runtime: 0.00890 seconds
2024/10/13 10:43:47 AM, INFO, mealpy.swarm_based.PSO.OriginalPSO: >>>Problem: P, Epoch: 6, Current best: 1345.25, Global best: 1345.25, Runtime: 0.00623 seconds
2024/10/13 10:43:47 AM, INFO, mealpy.swarm_based.PSO.OriginalPSO: >>>Problem: P, Epoch: 7, Current best: 1345.25, Global best: 1345.25, Runtime: 0.00926 seconds
2024/10/13 10:43:47 AM, INFO, mealpy.swarm_based.PSO.OriginalPSO: >>>Problem: P, Epoch: 8, Current best: 1345.25, Global best: 1345.25, Runtime: 0.00509 seconds
2024/10/13 10:43:47 AM, INFO, mealpy.swarm_based.PSO.OriginalPSO: >>>Problem: P, Epoch: 9, Current best: 1345.25, Global best: 1345.25, Runtime: 0.00566 seconds
2024/10/13 10:43:47 AM, INFO, mealpy.swarm_based.PSO.OriginalPSO: >>>Problem: P, Epoch: 10, Current best: 1345.25, Global best: 1345.25, Runtime: 0.00618 seconds
id: 25206, target: Objectives: [1345.25], Fitness: 1345.25, solution: [0 0 0 0 0]

As you can see, the epoch numbers and global best at what should be the 11th epoch is larger than what it should be.
